# How can I hide map types bar?

Tags: google-maps

How can I hide map types bar on Google Maps?

(hide Ter, and Earth on menu bar)

I create code from http://maps.google.com

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to look at this:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/controls.html

Short:

```
mapTypeControl: false
```

this will hide map types bar.

or here is init function:

```
function initialize() {
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33, 151),
    mapTypeControl: false,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
       myOptions);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Vahagn's answer will completely hide the bar.  But it's not clear from your question if this is what you want to do, or if you only want to hide just the options for Terrain and Earth.  If the latter, you could try:

```
function initialize() {
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33, 151),
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
            mapTypeIds: [
                google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 
                google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE 
            ]
    },
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
       myOptions);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to set the property `mapTypeControl` to false like this:

```
mapTypeControl: true,
```

here is  a [live example](http://www.svennerberg.com/examples/google_maps_3/properties.php) of a page that offers customization with respect to look and feel.